# Did mathcal stop working properly?

Tags: support, bug, mathjax

Does this question [Basic algebra of $\mathcal{O}_0(\mathfrak{sl}_n(\mathbb{C}))$ — Reference request](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/434710) look like this for anyone else?:

[image]

Those squares are supposed to be \mathcal{O}'s. As far as I can tell the LaTeX code is fine but it is rendering wrong for some reason. I remember looking at this question a couple days ago and it looked fine.

EDIT: Maybe I should say I'm on Chrome on a Mac.

EDIT 2: Changing the math renderer (as mentioned in the comments) fixed this for me; thanks!

Comment: I see it correctly (in Chrome under Linux).

Comment: Looks OK to me (also on Chrome on a Mac).

Comment: Hmm okay good to know, must be something wrong on my system.

Comment: Try https://www.documate.org/resources/what-is-a-hard-refresh-how-to-do-a-hard-refresh-in-any-browser

Comment: I use Chrome an Mac, and I got the same problem.

Comment: Have you tried [changing the math renderer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/30859) you're currently using for MathJax. From what I read here, not all of them rely on local fonts: [What is the difference between the 3 math renderers?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8881) (I do not know enough about MathJax to help - but maybe knowing whether this behaves the same for all renderers might help somebody to diagnose the problem.)
Unrelated: since the comments suggest that this might not actually be a bug, I have added the tag ([meta-tag:support]).

Comment: Another user recently posted a question about a similar problem on [math.meta.se] - so it might be worth checking later whether some new advice appeared there: [Why using \mathcal command produce a square?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35298)

Comment: Using Chrome on MacOS, I am able to reproduce this when the math renderer is set to HTML-CSS. If I change it to any other math renderer, then it is displayed correctly. I have not yet tested this on other browsers/devices.

Comment: It is currently showing up correctly for me on Chromium even with the HTML-CSS renderer.

Comment: The issue started for me after I updated to macOS Ventura. I left a [comment](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35298/why-using-mathcal-command-produce-a-square#comment166036_35298) about this on Mathematics Meta. I don't know whether it's the same for the OP.

Comment: @TheAmplitwist: yes, I think updating to Ventura had something to do with it for me as well.

Comment: I am also on MacOS ventura, and am reporting the same issue on another Chromium-based browser (Vivaldi).

Comment: Several posts on [math.mate.se] now have an answer posted by Davide Cervone, see "[Chrome doesn't display some symbols](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35669)" and other [questions linked there](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/35669).