# mathcal notation fails to render in Chrome

Tags: bug, mathjax

I recently noticed that "\mathcal" no longer renders. Example [post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/444091/when-is-prod-i-0-infty-i-x-i-x-it-0-for-zero-centered-gaussian-x-i)

[image]

but it renders fine in Safari
[image]

Chrome: 111.0.5563.146 (Official Build) (x86_64)

Safari: Version 16.4 (18615.1.26.11.22)

Perhaps need to roll-back to previous stable version of MathJax?

Comment: For me, it renders correctly also in Chrome. --

Comment: A recent question which seems to be about the same issue: [Did mathcal stop working properly?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/5508) Also: [I think there is a Mathjax bug for mathcal typesetting on some platforms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384924) on [meta.se] and [Why using \mathcal command produce a square?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35298) on [math.meta.se].

Comment: Did you perhaps upgrade to macOS Ventura recently?

Comment: Yes I did, this seems connected, is there a workaround?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Did mathcal stop working properly?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/5508/did-mathcal-stop-working-properly)

Comment: yes, changing math rendered to anything else worked