# Editor is not rendering the equations correctly

Tags: bug, mathjax

I haven't asked a question on Mathoverflow or Mathstackexchange but after while I decided to do so I have realized that the editor has got significantly worse. First of all it is significantly slower also sometimes it does not show the correct outputs. I have attached a photo to show the issue. I was wondering how is it possible to get around this issue? If I post the problem when the editor is not showing correctly is it going to get posted correctly or not?

[image]

Comment: You could include an example of such code in this meta post (in addition to the screenshot). It would serve also as a test - to see whether it is displayed incorrectly in the preview or even after posting. If it is only in preview, the tag ([meta-tag:markdown-preview]) would be suitable here.

Comment: @MartinSleziak I will try, sometimes it does not work but when the text becomes too long it becomes an issue. I didn't include because I did not want to spam the post with potentially long piece of text, but now I will try to add.

Comment: @MartinSleziak I was having this issue for at least a week (probably more) but it got fixed now (can't replicate it anymore), not sure whether someone saw it and somehow fixed it or it sometimes happens and sometimes doesn't. Right now rendering is fast. I will try later.

Comment: It looks like the markdown engine is using the `_` from the first `i_0` and matching it with the `_` in `i_1` and turning the text in between into italics by inserting `<emph>` (or some other HTML to get italics), which means MathJax won't find a terminating `$` for the one before `i_0`, but instead finds `$ and $` and typesets that.  The editor used to handle this correctly, but that may no longer be the case.  I'm not sure if that will be handled differently when posted.  You could try using `\_` instead of `_` and see if that works.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce the problem.  The following renders as expected for me, also in preview:

presheaves on $Top$ denoted by $p:\mathcal{F}\rightarrow C\mathcal{F}$ such that $i_0^*\circ p = id$ and $i_1^*$

In what browser and on what OS are you performing the editing?

Comment: The issue on MO got fixed immediately after posting this post. It still persisted on stackexchange, I haven't tried stackexchange in a while to see whether it still exists or not. I think it is a user based issue and probably something trivial that someone fixed for my MO account after seeing this post.

Comment: @user127776 That’s *extremely* unlikely. No one goes around randomly fixing things with user accounts (and I haven’t heard of a “user based” bug before, either). Even serious bugs take months or years to get fixed, and when they fix it, the devs make sure to post a reply so that we *know* they fixed it. If your problem disappeared by itself, the most likely explanation is that some of the javascript files or whatever was downloaded damaged to your browser (or failed to download entirely) due to some random network failure, and it fixed itself after it was redownloaded.

Comment: Interesting, right now my browser (Google Chrome) renders \mathcal{F} in your answer as a square. Reminds me of font problems in MS Word decades ago, I thought these phenomena were in the past...

Comment: @VladimirDotsenko What you describe in your comment might be the issue previously reported here: [Did mathcal stop working properly?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/5508)